# recovery on Linux Virtual Box

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, data-recovery

I am into a deep trouble .I was working on RHEL 5 64 bit OS on a Virtual Machine .
I was working as normal user(non root). Accidently i deleted the user on which i was working .

Can somebody tell me how to recover .My full code repository got lost .It contained my 2-3 weeks work .

Comment: Did you also deleted user home directory (check if it is still in /home directory)? If directory was deleted, make copy of your VM files, so that you can still work on it and recover files from copy. For recovery you should use tool which support your filesystem or go to professional data recovery company.

Comment: Maciek Users home directory is deleted .

Comment: How did you delete the user? Did you delete the user folder along with the account? Have you checked if /home/USER still exists? Normally deleting an account should not delete user's files unless explicitly requested. I guess you were root when you deleted the user, right? I would first check root's trash, even if it is very unlikely that you will find anything there. In the worst case scenarios: cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-recover-deleted-files-with-lsof-command.html or linux.com/news/enterprise/storage/8257-how-to-recover-lost-files-after-you-accidentally-wipe-your-hard-drive

Comment: mirix yes i did a sudo .user exists but not home directory . the links you send me are good solution if you have any process which is still running and having a lock on the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for my case , since i was using Virtual Machine , one can regularly take snapshots and then later you can get a .vmdk file from it .And there you are .

And if you havent taken the snapshots(same as i did) then you can mount your .vmdk on the similar type of OS , using VMWare's  VMware-mount-5.0.0-13124.exe utility and then can browse the virtual partition and get your files .

Cheers .